# All the numbers in one array are <= to another array

Tags: java, arrays, comparison, nested-loops

I am looking to create a function in Java that will take in two arrays or lists and be able to tell if the first array (source) 'fits into' the second (target). The target array has values that can not be exceeded in the source array.

For example:

```
[ 16, 16, 16 ] will not fit into [ 13, 13, 22 ]

[ 12, 12 ]     will fit into [ 16, 16, 12 ]

[ 12, 18, 14 ] will not fit into [ 10, 18, 14 ]

[ 12, 24 ]     will fit into [ 10, 12, 24 ]

[ 10, 10, 10 ] will not fit into [ 10, 10 ]
```

My current attempt (IANA CS Major!) is ok for 3-element arrays, and that's all I need to worry about for the short term, but I'm missing some logic in the inner loop that will prevent false negatives.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/1208514

```
private Boolean designFits(int[] max, int[] design) {

    Boolean designFits = true;

    Arrays.sort(max);
    Arrays.sort(design);
    int passCount = 0;

    if(design.length <= max.length) {

        for(int i = 0; i < max.length; i++) {

            for(int j = 0; j < design.length; j++) {

                if(max[i] <= design[j]) {

                    passCount++;

                }

            }

        }

        if(passCount == 0 || passCount > max.length) {
            designFits = false;

        }


    } else {
        designFits = false;

    }

    return designFits;

}
```

Comment: What does "fit" mean? Does the element in LHS need to be present in RHS? If yes, does this not mean that the LHS has to be a subset of RHS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this achieves what you're looking for:

```
private static boolean designFits(int[] source, int[] target) {

    //if source is bigger than target, it cannot fit
    if (source.length > target.length) {
       return false;
    }

    //sort the arrays
    Arrays.sort(source);
    Arrays.sort(target);

    //get the size difference between target and source
    int targetSizeDiff = target.length - source.length;

    //walk source:
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
       //compare source's value at index i with target's value at i + difference
       //if it's greater, source cannot fit
       if (source[i] > target[i + targetSizeDiff]) {
          return false;
       }
    }

    //at this point we know source can fit
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //false
    System.out.println(designFits(new int[]{16, 16, 16}, new int[]{13, 13, 22}));

    //true
    System.out.println(designFits(new int[]{12, 12}, new int[]{16, 16, 12}));

    //false
    System.out.println(designFits(new int[]{12, 18, 14}, new int[]{10, 18, 14}));

    //true
    System.out.println(designFits(new int[]{12, 24}, new int[]{10, 12, 24}));

    //false
    System.out.println(designFits(new int[]{10, 10, 10}, new int[]{10, 10}));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort the two arrays, then walk through the source array and try to fit each element into the target array. If element doesn't fit try the next place in target. If you run out of places it doesn't fit, if you successfully find place for all the elements it fits.

Answer (score 0):

With collections you could use containsAll method like this:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add(1);
list1.add(2);
list1.add(3);
list1.add(4);
list1.add(5);
list1.add(6);

List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList();
list2.add(1);
list2.add(2);
list2.add(3);

System.out.println(list1.containsAll(list2));
```

Comment: That would be perfect if I didn't need to also account for values in design[] that are smaller than any values in max[].

Comment: so, does it mean that, in your case array {1,2,3} would fit into {4,5,6}?

Comment: The problem would have been clearer with a fitting example where the lhs was not a subset of rhs

Comment: The second example of [ 12, 12 ] will fit into [ 16, 16, 12 ] is exactly that.

Comment: Sorry for getting the question wrong. I was kind of surprised that I couldn't find suitable method in Apache CollectionUtils. So I wrote some pretty ugly method using this library and understood how much I got addicted to all these utility methods, and how easy sometimes solution could be using just plain Java :) Sorry for not posting my solution, since the accepted answer is just a way more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem you want to solve looks like

```
return first.length <= last.length && max(first) <= min(second)
```

where "min" and "max" are functions that return the min and max element of an array.  If I understand correctly, it should be easy to code min and max.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort both arrays in **descending order** and compare each pair, if the comparison fails for any pair you can return false.

```
private Boolean designFits(int[] max, int[] design) {
    if (max.length > design.length) return false;

    Arrays.sort(max, Collections.reverseOrder());
    Arrays.sort(design, Collections.reverseOrder());

    for (int i = 0; i < max.length; i++)
        if (max[i] > design[i]) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The Collections.reverseOrder() is not available for array primitives, but I think I could have casted to ArrayList and then work on those. I am still grokking all kinds of Java casting and just got confused at how to make this work in the short term.

Comment: You're right, it only works for `Comparable` types so it would only work if the arrays were of `Integer`. Anyway the solution by Kublai Khan does exacly the same, only without sorting in reverse.